# Update Oracle table column with a sequence number based on varchar field in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am in need of help with the syntax to update an existing field in an oracle table with a new number sequence based on the ordering of another field that is VARCHAR2.

Current Table:

```
CODE    CODE_ORDER
A00     3
A00.0   4
A00.1   6
A00.9   8
```

Desired Outcome:

```
CODE    CODE_ORDER
A00     1
A00.0   2
A00.1   3
A00.9   4
```

The SELECT statement here gives me the desired results, but when I use it with an UPDATE statement, I receive an error.

```
UPDATE Table SET code_order = (select row_number() over (order by 
code asc) from Table)
```

The UPDATE statement displays this error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
merge
into table
using (
  select code,row_number() over (order by code asc) as new_code_order from table
) new_table
on (table.code = new_table.code)
when matched then update set
  table.code_order = new_table.new_code_order
```

I think this would also work in this simple case:

```
update (select * from table order by code) set code_order = rownum;
```

Comment: The MERGE works like a charm.  Thank you very, very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use subquery in SET clause as following:

```
UPDATE Table t SET t.code_order = (
Select tin1.rn from
(select row_number() over (order by tin.code asc) rn, tin.code from Table tin) tin1
Where t.code = tin1.code)
```

**Note**: thks query will work for sample data where there is no duplicate value exists in code column.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with..as` clause

```
update tab t
   set code_order = ( with tb as ( 
                      select t.*,row_number() over (order by code) as rn from tab t
                    )  
                    select rn
                      from tb
                     where tb.code=t.code)
```

considering the values for `code` column is unique

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b21645f3cb9a07840f0e40b1d4e5fcf)</kbd>